# Identify COM Ports on Windows

Tags: windows, serial-port

I trying to build a software in C# on Windows 10, that send SMS with an usb GSM Modem,
the issue I am facing now, is to to identify the COM Port the usb GSM Modem is connected on, to use the right one for sending routine.
can anyone help me to get the COM Port number for an usb port on Windows 10?

Comment: Use SerialPort.GetPortNames().  With some luck you only get one.

Comment: on my PC I have3 ports USB, but on device manager I have only one COM Port: COM5

Comment: Congratulations.  Only some USB devices have drivers that emulate a serial port.  The USB port is not relevant, only what you plug into it.

Comment: you need call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_COMPORT` for get list of com ports

Comment: but is possible to know with number is assigned to COM port of a usb port?

Comment: you not need  number (some time it can not exist at all). `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` give you name of interface, which can be used in `CreateFile`. if you need com port with some property need query it via `CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW`. say when you look in *device manager* - you can detect concrete com port by it *Details* tab ?